# Laravel Http Client return null

Tags: laravel, ssl-certificate, laravel-http-client

I need help in Laravel calling external API. I have two websites: Website A and Website B. Before installing SSL in Website A (http://website A): In Website A controller, I use `$response=Http::get('http://website B/api/ec23faa399beda')` and it returns value and everything runs well.

After installing SSL in Website A (https://website A):
using the same code `$response=Http::get('http://website B/api/ec23faa399beda')` and returns Null Value.

I added below code for check whether the HTTP client works or not :

```
if ($response->ok()) {
  $users = $response->json();
  dd($users);
} else {
  dd('Could not get response');
}
```

and it show 'could not get response'. But if i direct hit 'http://website B/api/ec23faa399beda' in a browser, it returns value.

Is it because of the SSL I installed on website A, or what? Maybe someone in this forum can help me.

Comment: are you testing in the local environment ?

Comment: nope, i testing on prod env

Comment: try to print $response->body()   what you get ,you might get idea

Comment: it says "SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found" . But why in local environment, it works. Only on production gives this error.

Comment: i cant help much on that unless debuging .just check all tables are created in database